# Some SE sites say Generalist badge can be earned multiple times

Tags: bug, status-completed, generalist-badge, badge-description

[image]

Some SE sites say that the Generalist badge can be earned multiple times:

- https://german.stackexchange.com/badges/15/generalist (beta)
- https://japanese.stackexchange.com/badges/15/generalist (beta)
- https://cooking.stackexchange.com/badges/15/generalist (launched site)

But some do not:

- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/badges/14/generalist (beta)
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/15/generalist (this site)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/badges/14/generalist (launched site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this issue has been fixed.